# Как запустить апплет?

Tags: java, applet

Win 7, установил java ire, jdk. В java control panel --> security ввел локальный диск в список исключений. IE вроде как разрешил активное содержимое.
Код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Applet example</h1><hr></br></br></br>
<div id="appletdemo"> </div></br>
<button name="callApp" onclick="sendNdisplay()">call applet</button>

<applet name="simpleapp" code="SimpleApplet.class" width="300" height="100"></applet>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src = "engine.js"></SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Код скрипта:

```
var s = "The text to and from applet";
var panel = document.getElementById("appletdemo");  
var aplt = document.simpleapp;

function sendNdisplay()  {
    var setok = aplt.setText(s);
    var responce = aplt.getText();
    panel.innerHTML = responce;

}
```

Код апплета:

```
package hivasya.chessApplet;

import java.applet.Applet;

public class SimpleApplet extends Applet {
    String s;

    public boolean setText(String text) {s = text; }

    public String getText() {return s;  }

} // end class
```

Компилировал двумя методами, с командной строки (javac) и с помощью Eclipse.
class-файл поместил в каталог, где html-страница и javascript.
IE пишет: объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод. И указывает на строку, где вызывается метод set.
Opera пишет:

> Can not read property 'setText' of undefined.

Пробовал в апплете создать метод init и закрасить прямоугольник цветом фона.
Никакой реакции. Почему браузеры воспринимают апплет как пустышку?

Comment: что апплет? бросай это дело. oracle в новом jdk вообще убила их

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Если хочется запускть из браузера - используйте Java Web Start.

Comment: Похоже вы правы. Я пока мучаюсь с локальным диском. А запустить у пользователя апплет из Сети не представляю как. Надо подписывать, а это дорого. Новая политика безопасности oracle убила апплеты.

Comment: Хотел, чтобы Java Script взаимодействовал с кодом. Поэтому привязался к апплетам.  Вижу, прошли времена апплетов. Через Java WS можно грузить любую хрень, которой и браузер для работы не нужен. Апплет же с ограниченной функциональностью - не моги. Долбаная безопасность.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что удалось прояснить. Если из кода апплета убрать package, IE8 выполнит вызываемые методы апплета, но проигнорирует метод init(). Если в коде указать пакет, а в каталоге страницы создать соответствующие папки (у меня hivasya/chessApplet) и туда поместить class-файл, IE8 при загрузке страницы выполнит init(), затем позволит вызвать другие методы, короче сделает все как надо. Однако гугл хром и опера выдают ошибку, что setText это не функция, init() тоже не выполняют. Для них апплет - пустышка.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в строке

```
var aplt = document.simpleapp;
```

У JS-объекта `document` нет свойства `simpleapp`. В этом случае в переменную `aplt` попадает значение `undefined` у которого, естественно, нет метода `setText`. В данном случае можно искать апплет так:

```
var aplt = document.getElementsByName("simpleapp")[0];
```

Но более правильным будет дать ему `id` и искать более быстрым методом:

```
<applet id="simpleapp" ...
. . .
var aplt = document.getElementById("simpleapp");
```

Comment: Спасибо, однако ошибка не здесь. Пробовал ссылаться на апплет по имени и по идентификатору. Результат тот же. Первоначальный вариант взял из книги Дэвида Флэнагана "Java Script". Мне удалось кое-что прояснить, но проблема не решена.